# The Viewport is working fine on inspect element but checking it on mobile it's not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This viewport is working fine in inspect element mobile view, but when I check it on actual phone devices it's not working fine.

Can you please explain what is my problem using that viewport?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">
```

Or should I use this viewport to fix the display on the physical mobile device?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Currently this is the viewport my using
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=yes">

Comment: it's working fine on inspect element however when I'm trying to view it on actual mobile it's not really working at all

Comment: Maybe a difference in screen resolution? It's not really possible to tell without details such as what "working fine" means, what devices you're testing with, and what the content is that you're trying to display.